# Pass ASP MVC3 textbox value to Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, query-string

I have a simple ASP MVC3 `@Html.TextBox` that I'm using to input search criteria. However, I need to append the value to the URL in an Ajax call as a query string. How would I go about this? Below is the HTML in the view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("searchString")
    <span onclick='GetCompName(searchString);'>
        <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Filter.bmp")" alt="Filter" />
    </span>
</div>
```

And here is the Ajax

```
function GetCompName(searchString) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://quahildy01/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$select=AccountId,Name,neu_UniqueId&$filter=startswith(Name,' + searchString + ')',            
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Unable to process your resquest at this time.");
        }
    });
}
```

I will also want to output the returned value into another text box. If anyone knows how to do that that would be really helpful as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the basic problem with your code is the searchString in `onclick='GetCompName(searchString);` always gonna be literally "serchString", you must specified the parameter in base the value in the input, like this `$('.searchbox').val()`

keep your javascript unobstructive.

HTML code

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("searchString", null, new { @class = "serachbox" })
    <span class="searchbox-trigger">
        <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Filter.bmp")" alt="Filter" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Set de handler for the event span click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.searchbox-trigger').click(GetProgramDetails);
});
```

and your ajax request

```
function GetProgramDetails() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://quahildy01/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$select=AccountId,Name,neu_UniqueId&$filter=startswith(Name,' + $('.searchbox').val() + ')',            
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Unable to process your resquest at this time.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This line seems to be throwing an error: `@Html.TextBox("searchString", Nothing, new with {.class = "searchbox"})`

Comment: VS doesn't like the `Nothing`, or `New With` keywords(?)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on that part of the answer? Relatively new to ASP MVC and haven't seen that syntax before.

Comment: sorry, thats are keywords for visualbasic, check out now, I edited to C#